# SQL Server ALTER COLUMN COLLATION not working

Tags: sql-server, collation

I've been issuing the usual statement for changing a column's collation, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE NAME> ALTER COLUMN <COLUMN NAME> nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NOT null
```

but unexpectedly the collation of the column (as viewed in the SSMS Properties) does not change afterwards despite the message displaying 'Command(s) completed successfully'. This happens with every table I've tried. I'm working with SQL Server 2014.

Comment: are you working on the same server as the one you're looking at?

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen Yes, I'm working on a single machine.

Comment: I'm asking because I could easily change a table on one server, then go searching for my changes on another server.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same. Even recreating the table with the needed collation doesn't work. No errors but collation doesn't change

Comment: From my understand @Miguel, you won't be able to change the collation if the DB's collation is set. You need to change the DB's collation first, but to achieve that, is better to create a new DB with the correct collation...